# Egorov’s theorem: Small compact set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $K \subset \mathbb R^n, n \in \mathbb N$, be compact and suppose the measurable $f_n: K \to \mathbb R$ converge almost everywhere to a function $f: K \to \mathbb R$.

By Egorov‘s theorem, for any $\varepsilon \gt 0$ we may find a measurable $A_\varepsilon$ with $|A_\varepsilon| \lt \varepsilon$ and $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $K \setminus A_\varepsilon$.

One can always find an $A_\varepsilon$ additionally being open.

**Question:** Can one also always find a *compact* set $A_\varepsilon$ (satisfying $|A_\varepsilon| \lt \varepsilon$ and $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $K \setminus A_\varepsilon$)?

Sadly, the measure of the closure of an open set may be much larger than the measure of the open set, so I am not really sure where to start here. However, I was also unable to come up with a counter example.

Comment: No you can't hope for that because $A_\varepsilon$ may be dense. Think about that you can change countably many points as you wish.

Comment: @Yanko: Sorry, I fail to imagine an example where all such $A_\varepsilon$ are dense – can you help me out?

Comment: Choose a dense set of points $\{k_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ such that $f_n(k_m)\not\rightarrow f(k_m)$ ($f_n$ is only defined almost everywhere so changing $f_n$ so that $f_n(k_m)=m$ will do the trick). If you want I can write more details but there's no much more than that.

Comment: Ah, that is indeed an easy example; I agree. However, that does not really answer the question I had in mind: For instance, is there more hope if we require $f_n \to f$ pointwise (instead of almost everywhere)?

Comment: It doesn't matter much. Instead of $f_n(k_m)=m$ let $f_n(k_m)=1-\frac{m}{n}$ so it convergence pointwise to $1$ but not uniformly on all $k_m$. An interesting question would be whether you can find $B\subseteq A_\varepsilon$ of measure zero such that $A_\varepsilon\backslash B$ is compact (I don't know the answer to that one, but I'd guess it's a no).

Comment: Again, I have to agree.

Let me try to weaken the statement again: Are there always $g_n, g$ with $g_n = f_n$ and $g = f$ almost everywhere such that $g_n \to g$ uniformly on $K \setminus A$ where $A$ is compact with $|A| \lt \varepsilon$?

Comment: Or, asked differently: Is there always A_{\varepsilon} which can be written as $A_{\varepsilon} = B_{\varepsilon} \cup C_{\varepsilon}$, where $B_{\varepsilon}$ is compact and $|C_{\varepsilon}| = 0$?

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: The following does not answer the original question, it only shows that $K\setminus A_\epsilon$ can be chosen compact.**

First, assume we already have the Theorem of Egorov:

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a finite measure space, that is, $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-Algebra and $\mu:\Sigma\to[0,\infty)$ is countably additive, and let $f,f_n:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, be $\Sigma$-Borel-measurable, such that $f_n\to f$ pointwise $\mu$-almost everywhere on $\Omega$. Then for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a (measurable) set $A_\epsilon\in\Sigma$, such that $\mu(A_\epsilon)<\epsilon$ and $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $\Omega\setminus A_\epsilon$. (See e.g. Donald L. Chon, Measure Theory, second edition, p. 81, Prop. 3.1.4)

Now, if we additionally assume, that - under the assumptions of Egorov - $\mu$ is inner regular, that is, there exists a topology $\tau$ over $\Omega$, such that $\tau\subseteq\Sigma$ and

$\mu(E)=\sup\{\mu(K)|K\subseteq E \text{ compact with respect to }\tau\}\ \ \ \forall E\in\Sigma$,

then in Egorov $A_\epsilon$ can be so chosen such that $\Omega\setminus A_\epsilon$ is compact with respect to $\tau$.

Indeed, for $\epsilon>0$, take the by Egorov granted $B_\epsilon\in\Sigma$, such that $\mu(B_\epsilon)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $\Omega\setminus B_\epsilon$ and use the inner regularity to find a compact $K_\epsilon\subseteq(\Omega\setminus B_\epsilon)$ with $\mu((\Omega\setminus B_\epsilon)\setminus K_\epsilon)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Set $A_\epsilon:=\Omega\setminus K_\epsilon$, then of course still $f_n\to f$ uniformly on the compact set $\Omega\setminus A_\epsilon=K_\epsilon$ and

$\mu(A_\epsilon)=\mu(B_\epsilon)+\mu((\Omega\setminus B_\epsilon)\setminus K_\epsilon)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$.

Both, the Lebesgue and the Borel measure on $\mathbb{R^n}$ ($n\in\mathbb{N}$) or on any measurable subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$ are (inner) regular (where the needed topology is the usual one on $\mathbb{R^n}$). (See e.g. W. Rudin, Real and complex analysis, third edition, p.47 and p.50, Thm. 2.20, (b); see also D. Chon for some useful Statements about regularity of measures.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering my old question. However, I think your $A_\varepsilon$ correspondents to my $K \setminus A_\varepsilon$. That is, I was wondering whether there is a compact set of measure at most $\varepsilon$ such that $f_\varepsilon \to f$ uniformly on the complement of this set.

Comment: You're right. My mistake. Edited my post so that notations coincide. Unfortunately then I must agree to Yanko, too.